# Python - How to search a tuple

Tags: python-2.7

I have a tuple , kind of list in Python.. the tpple is like this :

```
heartbeat_replys = ('0xFF', '0x0F', '0xF0', '0x00',
                '0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F',
                '0xE9', '0x19', '0xE6', '0x16')
```

I receive a row of 4 hex values which are somewhere in the tuple.. I want to search for the row and then send the next 4 hex values.

for example I receive `'0xff', '0x0f', '0xF0', '0x00'`
I want to search the tuple for the values and then send the next 4 hex values.. `'0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F'`... but if i receive other values I want to send then next 4 after those and so on.. I know how to split tuples and how to get the index of a tuple but I don't know how to search for a tuple value and then progress along the tuple and print out or send the next 4 values from the tuple.. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this

```
>>> heartbeat_replys = ('0xFF', '0x0F', '0xF0', '0x00',
                '0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F',
                '0xE9', '0x19', '0xE6', '0x16')
>>> def my_fun(msj):
        hear = map(lambda x:int(x,16),heartbeat_replys)
        msj  = map(lambda x:int(x,16),msj)
        n    = len(msj)
        for i in range(len(hear)):
            if msj == hear[i:i+n]:
                return heartbeat_replys[i+n:i+2*n]

>>> msj='0xff', '0x0f', '0xF0', '0x00'
>>> my_fun( msj )
('0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach:

```
heartbeat_replys = ('0xFF', '0x0F', '0xF0', '0x00', '0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F', '0xE9', '0x19', '0xE6', '0x16')
received = '0xff', '0x0f', '0xF0', '0x00'
for index in range(len(heartbeat_replys) - len(received)):
    if all([heartbeat_replys[i + index].upper() == received[i].upper() for i in range(len(received))]):
            print heartbeat_replys[ index + len(received) : index + 2 * len(received) ]
            break
```

Output:

```
('0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dict mapping after splitting the elements into tuples of groups of four element where the keys are each group and the values are the index they appear in:

```
heartbeat_replys = ('0xFF', '0x0F', '0xF0', '0x00',
                '0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F',
                '0xE9', '0x19', '0xE6', '0x16')


heartbeat_replys = list(zip(*[iter(heartbeat_replys)] * 4))


beats = dict(zip(heartbeat_replys , range(len(heartbeat_replys))))

arg = ('0xFF', '0x0F', '0xF0', '0x00')

print(heartbeat_replys[(beats[arg] + 1) % len(heartbeat_replys)])

('0xB0', '0x40', '0xBF', '0x4F')
```

Using modulo will cycle the list and I presume what you get is also uppercase, if not just call `str.upper` on the strings passed in.